# Unable to handle websocket and xhr request simultaneously using Nginx+uwsgi+django

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, uwsgi

I'm trying to use Nginx+uwsgi+django to establish a website where one of the task needs websocket. The system works well in django server (python manage.py runserver). However, when I make it on the AWS using Nginx+uwsgi, sth goes wrong. Though I modify the settings of Nginx+uwsgi, I find that the server is unable to handle websocket and xhr request simultaneously

The specific problems are as follows:

1) if I start uwsgi using `uwsgi --socket :8001 --module project.wsgi --http-websockets`, the websocket is able to be established but the message in django's "request.websocket" is always none and the uwsgi log shows `warning: async call without async mode`.

2) Next, I try to use async mode in uwsgi by `uwsgi --socket :8001 --module project.wsgi --http-websockets --async 10 --ugreen`. In this case, the websocket works well but the other xhr requests are blocked and cannot be handled by  the server until the websocket ends. For example, if one client is running the task with websocket, other clients cannot even log into the web.

Could you help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add following snippet as per your needs to your nginx config file located in `sites-available`.

This enables you to access websockets on url `ws://wsbackend/wspath/`

```
location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/lcs_daphne.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

This is switching protocol which upgrades `http` request to `ws` request.

You can refer to [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) documentation for more information on [implementation of websockets using nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)

Comment: Thank you! I have set like this but the problems still exist. The http requests are all pending until the websocket connection ends :(

Comment: I 've updated configuration in answer. Could you please try this? :)

Comment: After commenting I tried to add processes in the uwsgi by uwsgi --socket :8001 --module project.wsgi --http-websockets --async 10 --ugreen --processes 4. And this works! But I still have doubt that server has multiple threads even with one process, why it cannot serve websocket and http request simultaneously?

Comment: Note that adding `--processes 4` will enable you just to have 4 simultaneous connections. Each websocket connection will devour one process - This means, provided sufficient number of clinets, you will run out of number available processes on your machine.